# Как изменить цвет фона ListItem в зависимости от данных, получаемых из БД?

Tags: android, listview, sqlite

Здравствуйте.

Предположим, есть ListView, заполняемый адаптером из SQLITE БД. ListItem берется из кастомного Layout. Пусть в БД есть столбец "any"  и в нем, к примеру, хранятся либо 1, либо 0.

Как сделать так, что если в N строке в столбце "any" 1, то бэкграунд N ListItem одного цвета, а если 0, то другого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Устанавливать background программно в методе getView() в Адаптере. Если ваш Адаптер наследуется от CursorAdapter, то, я считаю, в bindView().

Comment: Можно чуточку подробней?